# Woocommerce shop sidebar widget not displaying

Tags: wordpress, themes, woocommerce, sidebar

This is something that I've been scratching my head over for a few hours now.

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.1 with the Muzak theme and have installed Woocommerce 2.1.12.

I wanted to replace the default sidebar content (pages, archives and categories) that was displaying on the shop pages for something more appropriate, so I went to Appearance/Widgets and found a widget area called Shop Sidebar. Great I thought, so I dragged a couple of the Woocommerce widgets into this area and saved it, thinking that when I went back to the shop pages my new sidebar would appear - wrong! It still displays the standard Wordpress sidebar content and nothing that I do seems to make any difference.

Is there something that I'm missing? Something that I'm failing to grasp? It seems a straightforward enough exercise but apparently not!

Any help or advice would be gratefully received :)

Tony.

Comment: Is that the only widget area you see? Wordpress installs a standard Widget area with Search, Pages, Archives etc. So just check if there are any other widget areas

Comment: No, I see (and am using) other Widget areas, a lot of which the theme installs. All the other Widget areas are working fine, it's just the Shop page shows the default sidebar content.
Since the initial post I have tried installing both the WooSidebars and Custom Sidebars plugins in an effort to setup my own Shop sidebar but even with these it still flatly refuses to show anything other than the default Wordpress content in the Shop sidebar. This is so frustrating! :)

Comment: Ah I see ok yes it looks like the theme developer made sure it uses the default sidebar. There is a way to change it and add your own sidebar content, but I dont know how well your knowledge is on editing php and html.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback msbodetti. I'm pretty proficient with HTML and I have dabbled with PHP. Since you're of the opinion that the theme developer has forced the use of the default sidebar in the Shop, I've contacted them to ask for support. Having dug around a bit deeper in the theme I see it's the theme that has created the Shop sidebar widget area, not WooCommerce as I had assumed, so it's even stranger why it won't display on the site! Any further help or advice would be a great help :)

Comment: All sorted!
Apparently the version of the Muzak theme I was using wasn't the latest (I was using 3.1.1 and the latest version is 3.3). Strange that Wordpress didn't inform me of the update... Now I've installed it all is working well. :)